# jQuery // var theHeight = window height minus 50px?

Tags: jquery, window, height, var, pixel

I am getting the window height like this:

```
var theHeight = "innerHeight" in window 
               ? window.innerHeight
               : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
```

I need a var that is theHeight minus 50px

How do I get that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using jQuery as your tag indicates, you can just use:

```
var theHeight = $(window).height() - 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Just pop it on the next line.

```
theHeight -= 50;
```